# Vidyo : No vendor id found in the keychain - ensure a proper entitlements file is present

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [VidyoClientConnector Initialize];

  c = [[Connector alloc] init:&_videoView ViewStyle:CONNECTORVIEWSTYLE_Default RemoteParticipants:2 LogFileFilter:"" LogFileName:"" UserData:0];//App Crash on this line.
}
```

I am implement video chat on my app so I am using vidyo framework but when we build our project then we got crashed . Please help me if anyone have some solution about the vidyo .

This is url of [vidyo.](https://vidyo.io)

I have got some error which is mention below :-

```
2017-04-17 11:06:39.196: ERROR: VidyoClient: [System thread]: /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_11_4.build.hbUgjRdPKe/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/VidyoLicenseApple.m:124: -[VidyoLicenseKeychain initAccessGroup]: SecItemDelete returned error -25300 for VidyoLicenseDummyId from the keychain
2017-04-17 11:06:39.198: ERROR: VidyoClient: [System thread]: /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_11_4.build.hbUgjRdPKe/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/VidyoLicenseApple.m:176: -[VidyoLicenseKeychain searchValue:]: SecItemCopyMatching failed with error -25300
2017-04-17 11:06:39.229: ERROR: VidyoClient: [System thread]: /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_11_4.build.hbUgjRdPKe/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/VidyoLicenseApple.m:176: -[VidyoLicenseKeychain searchValue:]: SecItemCopyMatching failed with error -25300
2017-04-17 11:06:39.229: ERROR: VidyoClient: [System thread]: /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_11_4.build.hbUgjRdPKe/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/VidyoLicenseApple.m:261: GetVendorID_: No vendor id found in the keychain - ensure a proper entitlements file is present
2017-04-17 11:06:39.229: ERROR: VidyoClient: [System thread]: /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_11_4.build.hbUgjRdPKe/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/VidyoEndpoint.c:4754: VidyoEndpointImplConstructAfterSharedPtr: Failed to get endpoint id
Assertion failed: (newVal >= 0), function LmiSharedPtrRefCountDecUseCount, file /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_11_4.build.hbUgjRdPKe/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/../../../SDK/Lmi/Os/LmiSharedPtrInline.h, line 51.
```

Comment: Is there any solution for this error? I got same error.

Answer (score 4):

Did you add keychain sharing capability to your project capabilities? 
Checkout 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html
On how to enable capabilities to your iOS project. 
Enable Keychain sharing, you limit your app to a set of keychain access groups just like the [VidyoConnector sample project](https://developer.vidyo.io/packages).

Add the keychain group - "VidyoLicense"

Comment: How have you done this.. i'm facing same issue. guide me. thanks

Comment: Did you try adding keychain sharing capability? Do you still get a crash after that?

Comment: yes i have added keychain sharing in capabilities. but same facing issue

Comment: make sure your build configuration include the Entitlement.

Comment: @SachinHegde Reference to `vidyo.io` I have created test project in swift IOS, followed all procedures as mentioned but my application is continuously crashing.  Error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ` on this file. `#1 0x0000000103aec9dc in LmiWindowCreateChild_ at /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_20_1_0_9.build.7uOSFpBWGF/source/SDK/Lmi/Ui/LmiWindowIPhone.m:394`  Even clean and build again but no success. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some important things setting up Vidyo. Hopefully, someone in future might find it useful.

1. Add the keychain group - "VidyoLicense"
2. Make sure your build configuration include the Entitlement (In Debug mode they are not set default in Visual Studio Mac.)
3. Set the Frameworks as : 
   AudioToolbox AVFoundation CoreLocation CoreMedia SystemConfiguration UIKit

for libVidyoClient in Native reference properties.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Reference to `vidyo.io` I have created test project in swift IOS, followed all procedures as mentioned but my application is continuously crashing. Error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`  on this file. `#1 0x0000000103aec9dc in LmiWindowCreateChild_ at /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_20_1_0_9.build.7uOSFpBWGF/source/SDK/Lmi/Ui/LmiWindowIPhone.m:394` Even clean and build again but no success. Please guide me