# Vidyo app crash on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video-conferencing, vidyo

I have created a Vidyo iOS app using Swift with following [this tutorial](https://vidyo.io/blog/how-to/vidyo-io-using-swift-build-ios-video-chat-app/#).

But I am getting app Crash on the following:

```
connector = VCConnector(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&vidyoView),
                                viewStyle: .default,
                                remoteParticipants: 4,
                                logFileFilter: UnsafePointer("warning"),
                                logFileName: UnsafePointer(""),
                                userData: 0)
```

Following is the Debugger Log:

> ERROR: LmiFile: [System thread]: /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_20_3.build.tO3KysfAv5/source/SDK/Lmi/Os/LmiFile.c:132: LmiFileOpen_: Error opening file v\217\206: Operation not permitted
>
> Assertion failed: (newVal >= 0), function LmiSharedPtrRefCountDecUseCount, file /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_4_1_20_3.build.tO3KysfAv5/source/SDK/Lmi/VidyoClient/../../../SDK/Lmi/Os/LmiSharedPtrInline.h, line 51.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check this: [App is Crash When I run my Vidyo code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43724320/8346251)

Comment: I have already added Keychain Capabilities. Still it Crashes on Second Run. First time It runs successfully if i run it Second time it Crashes. After some time if i try again it runs successfully for one attempt.
I am not sure what exactly is happening

Comment: @SaleelKarkhanis  Have you got any solution? I am experiencing the same problem. My app crashes again and again even I have followed the same mentioned steps. What is the reason? `Vidyo.io` lacking issues documentation

Comment: For runtime crashes, I have applied this way and It looks resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65793331/6135652

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is wrong.
Pass in `logFileFilter:` and `logFileName:` as regular Swift Strings.

```
connector = VCConnector(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&vidyoView),
                                viewStyle: .default,
                                remoteParticipants: 4,
                                logFileFilter: "warning",
                                logFileName: "",
                                userData: 0)
```

The parameter type for `logFileFilter:` and `logFileName:` is `const char*`. You can pass a String to a parameter of this type and it will be converted for you.

Source: [passing String to const char* parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308409/converting-from-swift-string-to-const-char?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

> You should be able to pass a String directly to a C function expecting const char * and it will be automatically converted to a null-terminated UTF-8 string

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are initializing the package before creating the connector:

```
// Initialize package
VCConnectorPkg.vcInitialize()

// Create connector
connector = VCConnector(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&vidyoView),
                                viewStyle: .default,
                                remoteParticipants: 4,
                                logFileFilter: "warning",
                                logFileName: "",
                                userData: 0)
```

This fixed the issue for me. Good luck!

Comment: Reference to vidyo.io I have created test project in swift IOS, followed all procedures as mentioned but my application is continuously crashing. Error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`  on this file. `#1 0x0000000103aec9dc in LmiWindowCreateChild_ at /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_20_1_0_9.build.7uOSFpBWGF/source/SDK/Lmi/Ui/LmiWindowIPhone.m:394` Even clean and build again but no success. Please guide me.

Comment: @Tekhe Hi, did you find any solution about your issue? I'm experiencing same thing even newly created Swift project.

Comment: For runtime crashes, I have applied this way and It looks resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65793331/6135652

Comment: @iamburak Teşekkürler Aslında Vidyo güvenilir değil ve fazla dokümantasyona sahip değil.