# EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime crash on LmiWindowCreateChild in Vidyo iOS SDK

Tags: vidyo

Getting a runtime crash like that while trying to connect room in Vidyo io SDK.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this file. #1 0x0000000103aec9dc in
> LmiWindowCreateChild_ at
> /tmp/SDK.Release.TRINITY_20_1_0_9.build.7uOSFpBWGF/source/SDK/Lmi/Ui/LmiWindowIPhone.m:394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did everything on documentation's said. Removing both `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` & `UnsafePointer` like below helped me overcome that runtime crash on newly created Swift app.

If you're still experiencing an error, checking sample app's (from GitHub) build settings may help too.

Documentations should be updated with up-to-date informations by Vidyo.io team.

```
    VCConnectorPkg.vcInitialize()

    self.connector = VCConnector(&self.vidyoView,
                            viewStyle: .default,
                            remoteParticipants: 4,
                            logFileFilter: "warning",
                            logFileName: "",
                            userData: 0)
```